# Broken tag popup for tag 'notify'

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

This is a bug report for Stack Overflow. I'm using Opera 91.0.4516.77 on Windows.

The **tag popup is broken** for the tag [notify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/notify). When hovering the tag's name with the mouse pointer, an orange layer appears at the top of the page. For other tags, however, the popup works fine and appears as expected.

[image: Broken tag popup in action]

Comment: I can reproduce this on both Google Chrome 106.0.5249.119 and Safari 16.0 on Mac

Comment: The bug is that the other tags lack that glorious, seasonally appropriate orange color, I assume.

Comment: Also broken in the latest FF on Linux Mint 21. Weird that it's specific to that one tag though. Can't reproduce it on any other tags, though haven't looked particularly extensively

Comment: Looks like hovering over tags creates an HTML element with the `id` value `[tag name] + '-container'`, and `notify-container` happens to be used elsewhere already. (At least, there are CSS rules for `#notify-container` that break things here.)

Answer (score 12):

As described by Ivar [in a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421063/broken-tag-popup-for-tag-notify#comment931406_421063), the problem is down to how the HTML for the popup with information is built, since it uses the tag name as part of the HTML: Simplified, it is:

```html
<div class="-container" id="{tag name here}-container"> 
    <!-- content -->
</div>
```

which for the tag [notify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/notify) would be:

```html
<div class="-container" id="notify-container"> 
    <!-- content -->
</div>
```

Subsequently, this picks up all CSS rules defined for the `#notify-container` selector.

---

The messages shown in a `#notify-container` normally show at the top of the page in orange. For example, if a question you currently have in a tab is closed.

[image: Question with a notification on the top reading "This question has been closed - no more answers will be accepted." The notification is on orange background.]

To force a message to show, you can use the following JavaScript code in the browser dev tools:

```javascript
StackExchange.notify.showMessages([{text: "hello world", messageTypeId: 1}]);
```

[image: Example of a regular message that shows at the top of the page. It is the text "hello world" on an orange background.]

Comment: This is why it’s a bad idea to store arbitrary information in the `id` attribute and pollute the namespace of possible IDs.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for reporting the issue and providing the excellent diagnostic details! The logic to generate tooltip container ids has been updated to be much more specific -- no other potential collisions with other ids or with the `#notify-container` have been identified.